# How do you control the c-rate at which a battery is charged with a variable power source? (and what determines current draw in batteries)

Tags: c-rate

I am new to electronics and don't know how you would determine how much current a battery is drawing from a source that varies in current (anything below 2 amps). This is because a battery can draw any amount of current as long as it isn't over the maximum c-rate specified by the manufacturer. In my case I am going to use 12v 2A max wall adapter charging a few nimh batteries (don't have certain batteries in mind) but I am focusing on just one right now. I want to be able to control the c-rate of the battery while it is charging (controlled by a circuit I am making) so that it is at a safe rate, which I believe would be a fraction of it's c-rate (C/5 to C/6?) How would you control the c-rate/the amount of current the battery draws if it is from a variable source? Sorry if I don't have enough information because I don't know that much on the subject.

Comment: Battery charging is a big subject.  Start here: https://batteryuniversity.com/  And whatever you do don't mess with trying to charge lithium batteries unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: You would normally use a battery charging chip that itself usually uses a sense resistor to measure the charge current and controls a pass element (PMOS transistor, etc) to keep the rate of charge at the desired level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the beginner, don't reinvent the wheel: use a purpose-made integrated circuit (IC) that "knows" how to properly manage the charging profile of the battery chemistry you are working with.  For some battery chemistries, the IC also needs to monitor the battery's temperature during charging to prevent battery damage and to prevent an explosion or fire.

In a nutshell, battery chargers are regulated power supplies that utilize three different modes of power output: constant current (CC) mode (bulk charging), constant voltage (CV) mode (absorbtion charging), and supplemental or "float" charging mode (maintaining the full charge on a fully charged battery).  Only one mode is operational at any time, but all three modes could be used in sequence—the so-called *charging profile*—to recharge a discharged battery: e.g., first CC mode, then CV mode, and finally float mode.

A battery charger has built-in logic (e.g., software on a microcontroller, or a purpose-made IC) that allows it to continuously test the battery's present charge level, and based upon that testing it selects the appropriate charging mode (CC, CV, or float).

> I am new to electronics and don't know how you would determine how much current a battery is drawing from a source that varies in current (anything below 2 amps).

The battery is not controlling, per se, the flow of current during charging; the battery charger controls how much current flows into the battery during charging.  Recall that the battery charger is essentially a power supply that has three modes of operation: CC, CV, or float.  In CC mode, the battery charger adjusts its output voltage until the desired amount of current flows out of itself and into the battery.  For example, a battery charger might adjust its output voltage to 14 VDC so that it forces a constant current of 1 Ampere to flow out of the charger and into a rechargeable 12 VDC battery.  *(NB: The numeric values I just mentioned are not actual values for a real battery charger; I simply made up some numbers for explanatory purposes.)*

There are various methods for measuring the current that's flowing out of the battery charger.  One method places a low-value resistor (e.g., 0.1 Ω)—commonly referred to as a *shunt resistor*, or *current sense resistor*, or *sense resistor*—in series with the current path, and the current that passes through this resistor creates a voltage drop across it.  The voltage across the resistor is typically applied to the two inputs of an instrumentation amplifier (i.e., to the inverting and non-inverting inputs, similar to an op amp's inputs). The instrumentation amplifier's output is then conditioned as needed to produce a voltage that is directly proportional to the current that is flowing through the resistor.  Typically, the amplifier's output voltage is then used to control the conduction of one or more series pass transistors that regulate (hold constant) the battery charger's output current (in CC mode) or output voltage (in CV mode).  This regulation action is a form of closed-loop feedback control, which unfortunately cannot be explained in "25 words or less" to the beginner or novice. (Not trying to be snarky here; control system theory is an advanced topic.)

Comment: Thanks for all the information about battery charger ICs, do you have any recommendations on ICs I should use?